# Allowing a user to put both text AND numbers in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

So, I've been working on an application, and noticed that the `EditText`s I'm using seem to default to `android:inputType="text"`. This is leaving me unable to put in numbers. I don't want any restrictions on what the user can put in. Is there a way to remove these restrictions?

Here's a sample of my problems:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleEntry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:hint="@string/title"
    android:singleLine="true" >
```

Note the lack of an `android:inputType` property, yet I'm not having any ability to put numbers into the editText field ([evidence](http://youtu.be/wZk-3PTaa5s)). This also occurs when `android:inputType="text"` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

`android:inputType="text"` means there is no restriction, User can enter Number , character or whatever..

or you can remove this line from Edit text tag..

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="text" >
```

it will let you enter number/chars etc

Comment: Then why can't I enter numbers into the field in either the emulator or on the devices I'm testing on?

Comment: It will let you enter whatever u want. U are still doing something wrong, Enable number keyboard and enter numbers..

Comment: Can you please point out where I am doing it wrong [here](http://youtu.be/wZk-3PTaa5s)?

Comment: I tried with your EditText declaration and can enter number, Your xml is fine, Something wrong otherwise

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13911/discussion-between-mowdownjoe-and-ankit)